# Is it possible to use Python to detect the system dynamic color mode (light or dark mode) for Windows?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

So I made an app, and it uses Tkinter for the UI. I am trying to make the app more user-friendly by allowing dynamic color modes. But I couldn't find a solution anywhere else. The plan is to fetch the current color mode and use it to decide `window.configure(bg=light/dark)` while `window=Tk()`. Any suggestions? :D

Comment: You mean the current color theme of the OS?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called `darkdetect` which can do this for you, `darkdetect.theme()` will return what theme your pc is using, hope this helps!